# Some Calendar with only Day and Month View

Tags: iphone, calendar, ios4, icalendar

In my app, I require a calendar with day view and month view.

Now the problem is that all calendars available are either having only month view or they are having an additional view for list view.

So can you suggest some calendars where in only two views (month view and day view).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tapku, Open source, it's on github. It has Day and Month, but not List view.

Comment: hey, i will look at it. thnx. :)